# React: pdf to cropped png

Tags: reactjs, html2canvas, react-pdf

in React, Is there anyone who know how to transform a pdf to a cropped png based on a search text, width of the pdf and only a portion height of the pdf where is the search. And to download it as a png file.

I am new in react-pdf development and I just want to check if it is possible and how to do it